# Replace only first match in multiple files with perl

Tags: regex, perl, replace

I need to replace a bit of text in multiple css files, but ony the first occurence.

I've tried replacing with:

```
perl -pi -e 's/(width:).*;/$1 100%;/' filename.css
```

But this replaces the value after every occurrence of 'width:' in the file, even though i'm not using the /g modifier.
I'm running this on a recent Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can stop the replacement after the first one:

```
perl -pi -e '$a=1 if(!$a && s/(width:).*;/$1 100%;/);' filename.css
```

Comment: Or, shorter: `... -e '!$x && s/.../.../ && ($x=1)'`. Also this only works if there is only one file like in the question. Unfortunately it doesn't work for multiple files.

Comment: @musikk, that's why I contributed my answer, which would work for multiple files.

Answer (score 9):

Nobody has addressed an implication of your actual title question. I recommend the same approach as used here, only modified:

```
perl -pie '!$subbed{$ARGV} and s/(width:).*;/$1 100%;/ and $subbed{$ARGV}++' *.css
```

The un-dimensioned `$ARGV` is the [*name* of the current file](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24ARGV). So for *each* file, you're replacing only the first occurrence. The "glob" `*.css` will send multiple files. If you do the scalar switch that other people are suggesting, you will modify only the first occurrence in the *first* file with that pattern. (Though, perhaps that is what you want.)

Comment: Good solution. I didn't know that `$ARGV` contains the name of the current file.

Comment: +1, feeding multiple files to a one-liner is very useful. Do you happen to know a way to get more files than `*.css`, for instance all the files in `myfolder`, recursing subdirectories? Yeah, that sounds like `grep` but perl can do more. :) For instance instead of `*.css` I tried `ls *.css`, it gave me a warning but did the work on the content of the files. Missing one ingredient do do this without a warning.

Comment: @zx81: The `*.cc` isn't expanded by perl, but by the OS. Or in the case of Windows, not at all. Doing it inside the one-liner, when it just expecting to process per line, is more difficult, and more of a module deal. You could put something in a BEGIN block to load `@ARGV`, but it gets more complex.

Answer (score 6):

If you read in paragraph mode, each file is only one line; hence the s/// without the /g modifier will replace the first instance in each file, then move to the next file:

```
perl -0777 -pi -e's/(width:).*;/$1 100%;/' *.css
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
perl -pi -e 's/(width:).*;/$a?$&:++$a&&"$1 100%;"/e' filename.css
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `s/(width:).*;/$1 100%;/o` would do?